# Will Millions of Namespaces in a Single AppEngine Application Cause Datastore Problems?

Tags: google-app-engine

According to [this link](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-appengine-python/u5s5HpMVSNY/5CrDCQtLzFYJ), "re-indexing is slower because each namespace is scanned 
individually."

We have tens of millions of namespaces in our application and have experienced recent issues deleting entities.  Namely, DeadlineExceeded errors, and the inability to delete individual entities for up to 5 hours, even deleting by the key directly.

If I could have confirmation that the AppEngine datastore will become almost unusable if there are too many namespaces, and possibly any suggestions for how to work around it (if this is the cause of our problems), that could be very helpful.

Comment: Are you referring to [Namespaces](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/multitenancy/multitenancy) or [Entity Groups](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/entities#Python_Transactions_and_entity_groups)?

Comment: Namespaces.  We have been creating a namespace for each individual functional test we run so the data can be reviewed after the test run if there was a failure.  This resulted in close to one hundred thousand new namespaces every day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He is probably referring to index building.  So, if you add a new index it will potentially take longer since each namespace will be indexed separately.  Basic operations should not be impacted by the number of namespaces, it only adds another component to the key.  Some operations, like indexing a timestamp, might even benefit from it - since the namespaces could allow the writes to be better distributed.

As far as the number of entities go, that should not pose any problems.  I work with applications that have tens of billions of entities and it performs quite nicely.

Comment: Turns out our issue was actually a "hot tablet" caused by thousands of individual entity deletions within the same key area simultaneously.  This was resolved by refactoring to deleting in batches of 500 entities.

Hot tablet information: https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/handling_datastore_errors

Since refactoring, there have been no problems with deletes, so it would seem unrelated to the number of namespaces.

Comment: Yeah, on occasion it is possible to run into hot tablets.  Ikai Lan actually [diagrammed](http://ikaisays.com/2011/01/25/app-engine-datastore-tip-monotonically-increasing-values-are-bad/) a nice explanation of this issue as well.  Most often, people hit them on writes.